# apache common configuration library: corrupted property file

Tags: java, character-encoding, apache-commons-config

I have got a corrupted property file from customer. The file is modified by application to update version number.  The code uses [apache commons configuration.](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/) When I tested, the library always seems to write files in iso-8859-1 format.

Code is simplified to below.    What is the possibility of following code write bad file?

```
import org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException;
import org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TestConfig {

    public void editVersionInfo() throws ConfigurationException, IOException {

        String filename = "C:\\temp\\VersionProperties\\Version.properties";
        PropertiesConfiguration config = new PropertiesConfiguration(filename);
        config.setProperty("application.version", "2011");
        config.save(new FileWriter(filename));

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ConfigurationException {
        TestConfig tc = new TestConfig();
        tc.editVersionInfo();
    }
}
```

Just in case - the bad file looks like below. It does not look like in any encoding. The file originally was normal property file with keys and values all in English(ascii chars).

> F????Co?aR??m??E?3#?? =
>   h\u00BD5j\u00B3\u00E0\u0096\u001D\u0081fe\u00BEo\b\u00A3\u0001\u00FE\u00A4\u00DE\u0000\u00FBi\"\u009C{\u00FC\u00D9\u00E2?c\u00F6\u00FF%B\u00A47\u00195\u001EXv\u0097/\u00D7x\u0099\u000E\u00A2gIX\u0014\u0097]k\u00882\u0003\u0014\u0097\u00BC\u00C3\u00AE\u00B4\u001E\u00B3R\u00E4\u00DE&\u0000\u0016\u009B\"7\u0085'\"\u00DCT*v'\u0092\u0007\u0091A\u00BD\u00ACl6~\u0097\u00C0\u00B1\u00D1\u00EB\u00FF\u00A8\u00F3\u0001'\u00BF\u0006\u001F\u009C\fk\u009F\u00C2\u00D9L^_\u0004J4\u00AF\u00D8\u00DAW\u00C4\u00CDj\u00E3\u0095\u00D1+\u00CE?\u0004>Z]\u00D7\u000B\u0098\u0016\u0095\u00AC\u00F7\u00E7\u009ATF\u0019\f)\u00A3\u00A9\u00DC\u00AD\u00ACtq5\u0085\u008E-\u00A3oH\u0000\u00C2\u0092\u00B5\u00F2\u008AG\u008F&\u00F5\u0017H\u0003!\u0083\u00B4\u008AV=\u00E0\u00EDj\u00F0\u00D0J\u00DB\u00CC\u00F2O\u00CE\u00BE\u00F0*4\u0006y~\u00C3\u00B7\"\u000B\u00E4\u00C0$>\u00F3\u00F2~\u00CE\u0097#\u00BAc\u00EC@\u00B4\u00AD\u009A\u00BAX\fF\u0083]\u00C2\u00D4\u00AB\u00F3\u009DQ\u0092\u00854z\u0097\u00FDG\t\u0095\u00E3}ty\u0082I\u00C3`\u009E
>   ??

Edit:  The customer environment is japanese.  How ever the application is always run with
 `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8`

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your customer has a different default character encoding to what you have. Check their setting of the property `file.encoding` (counterintuitively named, I know).

An alternative possibility is that you have two threads writing that property file. I don't know, but I suspect the Apache library won't be thread-safe by default.

Comment: @ Brian Agnew: Thanks for the clue. I will check the multi threading part. The file is definitely accessed from multiple processes. I guess the encoding may not be the cause.